Measurement of pressure using pitot tube
We know that pitot tubes are used in measuring velocity of a fluid or dynamic pressure. Now,in stagnation point which is basically the entrance of the pitot tube,the fluid particles are brought to rest. Now,if the particles are indeed brought to rest,how will water even enter the tube and create a water column? The pitot tube is essentially used to measure the velocity using that water column. I don't understand this point.

Water enters the column until the height of the column is sufficient to bring the new water (trying to enter) to rest.  Up to that time, you have a transient situation.

@ChetMiller could you please explain the mechanism of the water being brought to rest in a detailed post? I am trying to understand this topic but can't understand why only after reaching a particular height,the remaining fluid is brought to rest.

The transient solution involves the height of the column initially growing rapidly, and then slowing down and ultimately reaching the final column height.  This all typically takes place on a relatively short time scale.  The transient solution is somewhat complicated to obtain.  But the final steady state mechanics, where the water column is already in place, is fairly easy to understand.  Upstream, the water velocity is uniformly high, but, as the fluid approaches the stagnation the flow decelerates to zero.  To bring this about, the pressure has to be increasing along the central streamline

A pitot tube measures pressure. It does not measure velocity. It is calibrated to report velocity.
